# How to change the text in showConfirmDialog without using array?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, joptionpane

I am doing my assignment and one off it require a confirm dialog box to check if the people is single or married. But the question state the I'm **not allowed to use array**. I have search other answer but it all used array.

How to change the text in `showConfirmDialog` without using array?

Answer (score 1):

See [`JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(parent,message)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-). E.G.

```
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(parent, "Are you married?");
```